# Continous sidescrolling creates abnormality in display of background image

Tags: pygame, python-3.5

As the background scrolls along the side the the end of the image stretches and the rest of the image doesn't appear just the same hill elongated. It then suddenly resets. Also a portion of the image (a rectangle)is displaced from the rest of the image making it uneven and stays like that until it disappears from view.

[image: Normal background]

[image: Elongated background]

[image: Displaced backgound]

Here is the code I use to side scroll

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *

class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite): #Creates space background
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  #call Sprite initializer
        self.bgimage = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.bgimage = pygame.transform.scale(self.bgimage, (1333, 600))
        self.rectBGimg = self.bgimage.get_rect()

        self.bgY1 = 0
        self.bgX1 = 0

        self.bgY2 = 0
        self.bgX2 = self.rectBGimg.width

        self.movingUpSpeed = 5

    def update(self):
        self.bgX1 -= self.movingUpSpeed
        self.bgX2 -= self.movingUpSpeed
        if self.bgX1 <= -self.rectBGimg.height:
            self.bgX1 = self.rectBGimg.height
        if self.bgX2 <= -self.rectBGimg.height:
            self.bgY2 = self.rectBGimg.height

    def render(self):
        screen.blit(self.bgimage, (self.bgX1, self.bgY1))
        screen.blit(self.bgimage, (self.bgX2, self.bgY2))


pygame.init()

FPS = 15  # frames per second setting
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

window_width = 1333
window_height = 600

# set up the window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Deterred Journey')

BackGround = Background('scrollingBackground.png', [0,0])

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()


    #Adds images and text
    BackGround.render()
    BackGround.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my update function was checking bgX1 and bgX2 against height causing displacement and I set `self.bgY2 = self.rectBGimg.height`causing elongation. Since it's scrolling vertically bgX2 must be set to the width

updated function should look like

```
def update(self):
    self.bgX1 -= self.movingUpSpeed
    self.bgX2 -= self.movingUpSpeed
    if self.bgX1 <= -self.rectBGimg.width:
        self.bgX1 = self.rectBGimg.width
    if self.bgX2 <= -self.rectBGimg.width:
        self.bgX2 = self.rectBGimg.width
```